# Cluster analysis for different plant species with elevation, aspect, slope rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, spatial-analysis, spatial-cluster

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have a point shapefile for 5 different plant species and rasters (elevation, slope, aspect, canopy height). I am trying to find clusters for each species in terms of raster values (elevation, slope, aspect, canopy height). I need to figure out where cluster are spatially and significantly. So far, I ran extract multi values to points, and I have raster values for each point in attribute table. Then, I got stuck!

Do you have any ideas what to do next to have a visual layer ( raster or vector) where it shows the significant clusters?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into Ripley's K?

Comment: Thank you @Aaron . Yes I did. It produced a table if there is any significant clusters. I am looking for something more visual for a power presentation along with statistical values.

Comment: It looks like the data was colected in transects, as such point pattern and density analysis are not valid here. All I can think of is an actual cluster analysis such as k-means but, it is not avalible in arcgis.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Yes I thought the same. Now I am making Similarity Search rather than spatial analysis. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Just keep in mind the the similarity search is an implementation of the Cosine Similarity Index (CSI) which is a measure of similarity between two vectors  inner product space. This index is bested suited for high-dimensional positive data should be centered before the metric is calculated. The metric is bivariate in nature so, any multivariate representation is a function of averaging across all pair-wise comparisons of the CSI, which has not been proofed in the literature. I am quite skeptical over single observation matching using CSI as I cannot see how the math works out with k=1.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Well, this research idea was good but we failed to conduct with the proper method. Unfortunately, I am away from academia now and probably I will not get a chance to conduct this experiment again.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your problem could be the following:

1) Go to Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...

[image]

2) In the Create a virtual Layer window you could rename the default layer name, then press the Import button. After that, you will select the layer to embed and then you'll press ok.

[image]

3) Now, you have a virtual layer which will serve for our analysis. Open the virtual layer Properties, go to General tab and press the Query Builder button.

[image]

In the Provider specific filter expression please enter the following statement: "PlantType" = 'Persimmon'

[image]

5) If you wish, you could specify a label for the virtual layer features...

[image]

and finally you set a Heatmap style.

[image]

6) Now, you can easily identify where the Persimmon cluster is spatially significantly. Of course, you can set more complex queries, as desired.

[image]

The entire project can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w52hl1wjswayn6/Plant_Species_Cluster_Analysis.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation and answer but I am working with Arcgis Desktop version. I need to start learning qgis soon.

Comment: All you are doing here is creating an on-the-fly density map. There is no statistical significance and it does not reflect clustering of the associated covariates. It is also using some type of bandwidth plugin to calculate the density, as such you have no way to interpret the results or test any type of hypothesis of distance/density relationships, invariant of any covariates.